# Can't use Javascript variable as dictionary key but raw string works perfectly

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I have a dictionary that doesn't seem to work when I used a variable instead of  raw string e.g. `dict[var1]['string']` does not work, but `dict['notVarButString'][string]` works fine. How can I use a variable as a dictionary key? Here is my script below. I'm using `onchange="funct(this)"` on an html element.

```
<script>
  function funct(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;
    document.getElementById('_' + obj.id).innerText = dict[id]['string1']['string2'];
  }
</script
```

This does not work for some reason. Like I said earlier, if I just replace `id` with an actuale string, then the results I would expect will render inside of the html tag. I've also tried to use `toString()` in case it was an integer somehow, but that doesn't work either. If I replace the entire dictionary with just `id`, I will see that variable as the innerText. If do `id + dict[id]..` nothing shows up. How can I fix this?

Comment: The value of the variable is not the same as the working string.

Comment: @Teemu Care to explain why? I'm pretty new to Javascript. Is there a way that I can use a variable for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know why, but you can always check the value using DevTools. Add a break point to the second line of the function, then refresh the page. You'll see the script in  the DevTools Debugger tab, then just hover over `id` to see its value.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try that